# Why are the variables not passed to the query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP code to get values from drop down menus and to used them in a query. However they are being ignored. Here is an example:

```
 $sortIn = $_POST['SortIn'];
    $sortBy = $_POST['SortBy'];

    $myquery = 'SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY "$sortBy" "$sortIn"' ;
```

However the query executes as `$myquery = 'SELECT something FROM somewhere'`

Comment: Because you need to use `"` to begin string concatentation if you wish to not escape your variables.

Comment: And remember, you SHOULD not use double-quotes `"` inside a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
 $myquery = "SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY $sortBy,$sortIn";
```

Because in single quotes `$sortBy` and `$sortIn` doesnt interpreted as variables.

Comment: I'd also suggest to sanitize these variables before appending them to the query to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks Guilherme! I will not put this work online, it is just for a simple demo purpose.

Comment: @Guilherme Sehn  yes, of course. Its not correct way to passing variables into SQL query.

Comment: Forgive me for putting it like this.. but that's a rubbish reason to not sanitize your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$sortIn = $_POST['SortIn']
$sortBy = $_POST['sortBy']

$myQuery = "SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY '".sortBy."','".SortIn."'";
```